# What do I do with new installed subversion

Tags: svn

So I have installed subversion and am extremely new to it, about 2 hours new in fact.

I am using because I want to track changes made to my website.

I have a site folder where I keep my website files and it has a few pages used for the actual site and then all the images and css stylesheets etc.

At first do I commit add and commit all the files (php, html, css and images) to the svn repository or just the (php and html) or (php, html and css). Im really confused with this as to whats the best practice and what everyone else does.

If I have to upload everything, so images and all, then for every update I do to my site, do I then upload all my files again, or just the file I updated?

Comment: Start with reading (parts of) a book. You can start with http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add all the files for your project and commit them. General rule is that anything that can be "built", "generated" etc by your build process is not checked in to the repo.

Then as you make modifications and commit, it is only the modifications that are added to the repo. The files are not a added again and again. New files, are of course, added when you add them to the repo.

One thing is that you have to consider how you move / rename the files. Use `svn cp` or `svn move` or appropriate commands for the operations so that SVN recognizes that it is the same file moved / renamed / copied and will not add the file again.